# Hibernate dialect autodetection

Tags: hibernate

I read that Hibernate can manually try to find appropriate dialect for a given database, but it is limited to the built-in dialects I think (because when I don't specify dialect for my sqllite database I am getting exceptions).

Is there a way to add to hibernate other dialects as classes that are part of someone project, so he could make use of them for dialect loop-up?

EDIT:
I am using `3.6.0.Final` version of Hibernate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There sure is.  You have to supply a custom DialectResolver.  You do that using the `hibernate.dialect_resolvers` setting which names a comma-separated list of DialectResolver implementations.

Comment: I added `<property name="hibernate.dialect_resolvers" value="pl.meble.taboret.utils.SQLiteDialectResolver"/>` to my persistence.xml but I am still getting errors about dialect.

Comment: What version of Hibernate (always good to mention that kind of stuff in the initial post/question)?

Comment: The version I use is `3.6.0.Final`

Comment: Nope, I added `System.out.println` to the `protected Dialect resolveDialectInternal(DatabaseMetaData metaData)` method in my class that extends `AbstractDialectResolver` and nothing shows up

Comment: Ah because in 3.6 resolvers *have* to be defined in hibernate.properties.

Comment: I presume that Hibernate autoamtically scans classpath for this file?

Comment: Hibernate does a resource lookup for hibernate.properties, if that is what you mean by "scans classpath"